# byte array to pdf corrupt pdf

Tags: java, servlets, outputstream

This is my code, the fileByte in an array with the contents of a PDF in it.
However, the file is corrupt and I cannot read from it. What is wrong here? Thanks!

```
HttpServletResponse response = (HttpServletResponse) FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getResponse();
response.addHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment;filename=test.pdf");

   ServletOutputStream outputStream = response.getOutputStream();
    response.setContentType("application/pdf");
    response.setContentLength(fileByte.length);
    outputStream.write(fileByte); 
    outputStream.flush();
    outputStream.close();
```

Comment: Nothing wrong here. Are you sure `fileByte` is correct? Try to write it to file.

Comment: I create a file, and then I convert the file to byteArray in order to send it over. Could you show me how to do it directly? I use the iText pdf renderer to create a pdf file. If I save the file with the renderer I can open it without any problem.

Comment: Just write `FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(new File(filename)); fos.write(fileByte); fos.close();`. Check the file, I think it will be the same as you download.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check this:

[Send pdf to http client](http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/Java/0419__PDF/SetContentTypeandtransferPdfdocumenttoclient.htm)

First make sure you have the correct bytes, so try to write it a file and validate whether the byte array is good. Once you get through this then writing it to the outputstream for an http response should be good.

Hope it helps!

Comment: Thanks, the byte[] was wrong somehow. After changing some pieces, like described in the URL you provided I got a working system. Thanks!